# I'm too mathematic minded, which textbooks will suit me better?

Tags: resource-recommendations, mathematics

I found the most physics textbooks a lot forgetful, I think that I need a more mathematic/axiomatic approach to physics, could someone list the best ones in those courses?

- Electromagnetism
- Structure of Matter
- Classical Mechanics
- Thermodynamics
- Solid-State Physics
- Optics
- Computational Physics
- General Relativity
- Statistical Mechanics
- Quantum Mechanics

Comment: -1. No effort. So basically you want recommendations for textbooks in every area of physics taught at university?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest some books:

- Statistical Mechanics: [Ruelle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9810238622)
- General Relativity: [Wald](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226870332) or [MTW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716703440)

I'd edit this post if I can think of some more.